# GRUB menu edit protection only

Tags: ubuntu, boot, passwords, grub

I set up the GRUB password protection on my Ubuntu LTS 14 64bits. To do that I generated a hash of the password with grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2. Then I edited /etc/grub.d/40_custom to add those 2 lines:

```
set superusers="admin"
password_pbkdf2 admin grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.EC81D.............
```

After updating the Grub and rebooting, the password is present BUT everywhere. If I want to boot on Ubuntu, I have to enter my password. I'd like to set up the password only for 'e' editing GRUB menu. (to avoid single user mode)

Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I just found the solution.
I just need to add the unrestricted attribute to the menuentry in 10_linux file as described here:
http://daniel-lange.com/archives/75-Securing-the-grub-boot-loader.html

It will keep the password while editing.

Answer (score 0):

To allow Grub to boot the default option without a password, but require a password for everything else, including editing the options, edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and find the `menuentry` lines and add `--users ''` and `--unrestricted` like this:

```bash
if [ x$type != xsimple ] ; then
    # ...
    echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --users '' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
else
    echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
fi
```